# Reusing symbol in SVG pattern without blurring

Tags: svg, symbols, svg-pattern

I found that symbol reused in pattern looks blurry.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70mm" height="84mm">

<defs>
<symbol id="Pole" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
    <path fill="#666" fill-rule="evenodd" d="m 9 9 l 3 6 l -3 6 l 6 -3 l 6 3 l -3 -6 l 3 -6 l -6 3 z m -6 4 v 4 h 10 v 8 h 4 v -8 h 10 v -4 h -10 v -8 h -4 v 8 z m 12 -13 a 1 1 0 0 0 0 30 a 1 1 0 0 0 0 -30"/> 
</symbol>

<pattern id="Poles_StepDependedWidth" x="0" y="0" width=".25" height="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="red" opacity="0.25" />
    <use href="#Pole" width="7mm" height="7mm" />
</pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="7mm" y="4.5mm" height="7mm" width="70mm" fill="url(#Poles_StepDependedWidth)"/>
<use href="#Pole" x="0" y="4.5mm" width="7mm" height="7mm" />

</svg>
```

Playng with combination of patternUnits, viewBox (for pattern and symbol) didn't fix the blurring symbol in pattern (with red background).

[Here is an image showing that the edges are not so sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skkxO.png)

[More complex image showing blurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRUsl.png)

Comment: Looks OK to me on Firefox on a Mac. What am I looking for exactly?

Comment: Thanks for attention. I've attached to post image showing that the edges are not sharp in Chrome on Windows

Comment: Report it to Chrome then if you wish: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/ although really it's just antialiasing so I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: It's not a Chrome bug. Safari on mac also blurring symbol in pattern.

Comment: As I said, it's antialiasing, it's expected. You can set shape-rendering="crispEdges" if you don't like it but you might think that's worse.

Comment: So why antialiasing looks different in same size in symbol and same symbol in pattern?

Comment: Key point - same size of graphical object symbol and symbol in pattern.
Pattern should just repeat this graphics without modification.

Comment: Colour in pattern does not affect and was added to see pattern area. When you remove colour background, you will see different rendering of same graphical objects.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem is caused by accumulation when rounding values.
In svg header for width/height need to use integer measurements (in pixels).
Here is an example where the symbol is rendered identically.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">

<defs>
    <symbol id="S" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
        <path fill="#666" fill-rule="evenodd" d="m 9 9 l 3 6 l -3 6 l 6 -3 l 6 3 l -3 -6 l 3 -6 l -6 3 z m -6 4 v 4 h 10 v 8 h 4 v -8 h 10 v -4 h -10 v -8 h -4 v 8 z m 12 -13 a 1 1 0 0 0 0 30 a 1 1 0 0 0 0 -30"/> 
    </symbol>

    <pattern id="P_BoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width=".5" height="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <use href="#S" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
    </pattern>

    <pattern id="P_SpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <use href="#S" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>

    <use href="#S" x="0" y="30" width="30" height="30" />
    <g stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity=".25">
        <rect x="30" y="30" height="30" width="60" fill="url(#P_BoundingBox)" stroke="red"/>
        <rect x="90" y="30" height="30" width="60" fill="url(#P_SpaceOnUse)" stroke="blue"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```